# how to detect keydown/keypress in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, keydown

I want to detect keydown/keypress in kendo grid to edit or remove row of
grid, but my grid is not defined in jquery.

datasource send to grid with json from controller

```
<div id="ParamsDb">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ParamKendo.Models.parametric>()
        .Name("gridDetail")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.kodfarei).Width(50).Title("کد");
            columns.Bound(c => c.sharh).Width(150).Title("شرح");
            columns.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Edit().Text("ویرایش").UpdateText("ثبت").CancelText("انصراف");
                command.Destroy().Text("حذف");
            }).Width(172);
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text(" جدید "))
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))            
        .Sortable()
        .Resizable(rl => rl.Columns(true))                                
        .Selectable(sl => sl.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5)
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.adder))
            .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Home", new { intParent = ViewBag.IntParent }))
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetDetail", "Home", new { intParent = ViewBag.IntParent }))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Inline_Update", "Home"))
            .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Inline_Destroy", "Home"))
        )
    )
    </div>

    $("#gridDetail").on("keyPress", " tbody > tr", function (e) {
        alert("1");
    });
```

Comment: well it should be "keypress" not camel case and unless an element has focus in the table, you are not going to be capturing keypresses. You need to listen for it on the body/document.

Comment: thanks for epascarello